# I have to add .xhtml to image in css

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have to add .xhtml in an url in css in order to have my image considered, else it's not found(no typo).

ex, this is found:

```
background-image: url(flags/flags-32.png.xhtml);
```

this is not found:

```
background-image: url(flags/flags-32.png);
```

my file is under resources/css/flags.

I've also a side question that is indirectly tied to this :

- I've read somewhere that one shouldn't have extensions like .png.xhtml or .script.xhtml as it could impact negatively performances. I can't find the source of where I read that but I'd like to know why that is the case (maybe it's because of cache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when .xhtml is appended to the end of a file the url is :

```
javax.faces.resource/...
```

while if you want to access a .js file directly for example the url is :

```
resources/script/myscript.js
```

don't forget the **s** in resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add resource before your flag folder

> url("#{resource['flags/flags-32.png']}");

Comment: This is how I found out I had to add .xhtml, so I know about that. Thing is I'd like not to have the .xhtml at all(because of my side question)

Answer (score -1):

You should try like this

```
background-image: url(../images/imageName.gif);
```

if your folder structure like this `resources->images->imageName.gif`.